# How do I use Python input while using pynput as well? Python input not waiting for user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, command-line-interface, pynput

I am using pynput primarily because there are cases when I don't want the user to have to press enter after supplying an input e.g. when using arrow keys to navigate a CLI.

There are cases where I want to use Python's `input` function to extract a user's input and store it in a variable. My problem, however, is the `input` function is no longer working as normal and for a line such as

```
inp = input("Please enter number of seconds for data recording: ")
```

The prompt is printing but the program doesn't wait for the user input as it normally would.

So how do I get the behaviour I need. The way I'm using pynput is mostly as follows:

```
with keyboard.Events() as events:
    # Block for as much as possible
    event = events.get(1e6)
    if event.key == keyboard.Key.down:           
        x = 1
    return x
```

Comment: I haven't used pynput before, but I'd guess that something "fills" the input before the user has a chance to use his keyboard. I'll read the doc about pynput and come back in a while.

Comment: Use the `curses` module if the target is a *nix machine or the `readchar` module instead.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. Let me have a look.

Comment: Welcome! Glad to solve your problem.